# IOS 6.1 Game center auto matchmaking getting stuck

Tags: ios, ios6, game-center

In my game I am using auto-match making. Its working perfect for IOS 5.0, but with IOS 6.1 I am having trouble connecting. The match making processing is getting stuck at **"Connecting..."**

Here is the code:

```
- (void)findMatchWithMinPlayers:(int)minPlayers maxPlayers:(int)maxPlayers
                 viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                       delegate:(id<GCHelperDelegate>)theDelegate {
    GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    request.minPlayers = minPlayers;
    request.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;

    GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];
    mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

    self.presentingViewController = viewController;
    [presentingViewController presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];

}


#pragma mark GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate
// The user has cancelled matchmaking
- (void)matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController {
    [presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

// Matchmaking has failed with an error
- (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Error finding match: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}

// A peer-to-peer match has been found, the game should start
- (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKMatch *)theMatch {
    [presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    //self.match = theMatch;
    //match.delegate = self;
    //if (!matchStarted && match.expectedPlayerCount == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Ready to start match!");
    //}
}
```

--------Note Again that this is perfectly working in IOS 5----------

Comment: I've noticed this, it might be coincidence but it seems to happen when connecting between iOS versions, eg 5.1 to 6.1. When connecting between devices of the same version it doesn't hang like this. It doesn't happen every time however - sometimes the game will proceed when the versions are different.

Comment: yes..exactly.. I think its a bug in GameCenter.. Damn I need to write my own server..

Comment: Me too, or at least something in combination with GC if possible - I'd really like players to connect to a "Game Lobby" area that shows other waiting/available players.